# How to get return from event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a draft code:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="content">
    <input type="button" name="validate_button" id="validate_button" value="Validate" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" id="submit_button" value="Send" />
</form>

<script>
$('#submit_button').click(function(e) {
    if (!($('#validate_button').click()))
        e.preventDefault();
});

$('#validate_button').click(function() {
    if ($('#content').val() === '')
        return false;
    return true;
});
</script>
```

I want when clicking `submit_button` to run the event handler of `validate_button` and decide for submitting or not the form. Obviously, my condition `!($('#validate_button').click())` is not correct since it returns a jQuery object. ***How may I get return results of the event handler itself?***

P.S. Do not suggest to put the condition `$('#content').val()===''` inside the first event handler...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a function and call that in both click handlers:

```js
$('#submit_button').click(function(e){
    if (!validate())
      e.preventDefault();
});

$('#validate_button').click(function(){
    return validate();
});

function validate() {
    if ($('#content').val()==='')
      return false;
    return true;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and use it as handler to the `#validate_button` click and it can be called from `#submit_button` click handler too.

```
// Function to validate the value of `#content`
// Return false when value is empty, true o.w.
function validate() {
    // Trim the leading and trailing spaces
    // Note: Empty string in JS is falsy
    return $.trim($('#content').val());
}

$('#submit_button').click(function (e) {
    // Other code

    return validate();
});

// Pass the function reference to the click()
$('#validate_button').click(validate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not not use JavaScript at all?

```
<input type="text" id="content" required />
```

Comment: `not not` => `!!` => true, i.e. Use JS :P

Comment: @Tushar It's reverse speaking anyway - "why not" meaning "do this", "this" being "not use JS", therefore "don't use JS". Ah, English...

Comment: Correct(_in English_), but I speak JS :)